# Web app development with Google App Engine's webapp2 in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

What are some nice books covering complete web applications development using Google App Engine's webapp2 framework in Python?

Answer (score 4):

[Programming Google App Engine](http://ae-book.appspot.com/) is being updated to cover the Python 2.7 runtime and webapp2 (a pre-release is available [here](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920017547.do)).

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for. Can you suggest any other good online resources or books that completely cover webapp2?